# Static External IP addresses from ISP

Tags: networking, ip, isp, static-ip

I have internet service provided by Spectrum Business, with a static external IP to more easily run services like FTP, Gameservers, and the like, but I want to run my own router so I can have more control over internal network parameters and filtering. Spectrum Business says I *must* use their provided router to have the static external IP. To my knowledge, that isn't how static external IPs work. Do I really have to use their provided router, or can I unplug it and use one of my own?

Comment: Try it & see what happens... or read the contract you signed.

Comment: How are they delivering your Internet?